# Get the body section of rabbitmq message

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have setup a simple listener for rabbit mq

```
@RabbitListener(queues = SECOND_QUEUE)
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
     LOGGER.info("second queue listener.........");
     LOGGER.info(message.toString());
    }
```

and this gives a message of this format

```
 (Body:'1460' MessageProperties [headers={}, timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, receivedUserId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, correlationIdString=null, replyTo=null, contentType=application/x-java-serialized-object, contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=bottomlesspit, receivedDelay=null, deliveryTag=1, messageCount=0, consumerTag=amq.ctag-PpEjG_BokAg-A4wllCgeqA, consumerQueue=bottomlesspit])
```

on the console.

I am also interested in processing the message on the client side as well and i have this

```
var onConnect = function() {
   client.subscribe("/topic/messages", function(d) {
   var str = d.body
   var res = str.match(/Body:\'(.+)\'/);
   console.log("I control this",res[1]);
   });
 };
```

I just want to get the body in java since its the only part i am interested with for the time being.

Is there a function that has already been implemented in java and on stomp for getting the body section only?.

Comment: I believe `message.getBody()` is what you need - it will return byte array, which you need to convert knowing the message format you are using.

Comment: Wow, that worked.Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`message.getBody()` is what you need - it will return `byte[]`, which you need to convert knowing the message format you are using:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = SECOND_QUEUE)
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    byte[] body = message.getBody();
    // do what you need with the body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @syntagma suggestion, this worked for me

```
@RabbitListener(queues = SECOND_QUEUE)
public void onMessage(Message message) {
 LOGGER.info("second queue listener.........");
 //LOGGER.info(message.toString());
 byte[] body = message.getBody();
LOGGER.info("This was the output from the listener "+new String(body));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your data like this:

```
@Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] pattern) {
        yourmap.put("data", message);
        send();
    }
```

Then,

```
String s = yourmap.get("data").toString();
```

You can get the published data from the stream.

I hope this will help.